# Apache virtual host with regex

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have one domain: www.abc.com

I want to use Apache virtual host to get this:

```
www.abc.com/index.html?id=m1 ,www.abc.com/index.html?id=m2
```

to visit

```
/home/m/index.html
```

and

```
www.abc.com/index.html?id=a1 ,www.abc.com/index.html?id=a2
```

to visit

```
/home/a/index.html
```

Can I use apache regex to complete this without .htaccess, like this:

```
<VirtualHost (www.abc.me/*?id=a*):80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laohu_v1
    ServerName www.abc.me
    ServerAlias www.abc.me/*?id=a*
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you only need or should use .htaccess when you don't have full access to your server. Vhost doesn't require to be put in .htaccess. Our Apache config uses none at all ;)

Here is how your vhost could look like. But if you only host one domain with entrance over one port on your server, leave out the `<VirtualHost>` directive and put the rewrite directly in your server's config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laohu_v1
    ServerName abc.me
    ServerAlias www.abc.me

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)\d$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /home/%1/index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)\d$` change that to `(.)` if only ONE character is in front of the digit. And if you need more than one digit, change that to: `\d+`